# Powershell nothing returned from C#, same code runs in ps prompt with \r\n's removed

Tags: c#, powershell

```
string cmd = " $srv = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server('" + svr + "')" + Environment.NewLine;

cmd += " $srv.Logins | where-object {$_.Name -eq 'DOMAIN\server55' } | select-object 'State'" + Environment.NewLine;
```

That code is added between the PSSnapin & PSSession code then invoked:

```
util>string prep = "$hasSnapin = get-pssnapin | Select { $_.Name.toLower().Trim() = 'sqlservercmdletsnapin100' }" + Environment.NewLine;

util>prep += "if ($hasSnapin -eq $null) { Add-Pssnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100 }" + Environment.NewLine;

util>cmd = prep;
util>cmd = "$pssessSql = New-PSSession -ComputerName " + svr + Environment.NewLine;
util>cmd += " Invoke-Command -session $pssessSql -ScriptBlock {" + Environment.NewLine;
util>cmd += "    " + " sqlps -nologo -noprofile -command {" + Environment.NewLine;
util>cmd += "    " + command + " }" + Environment.NewLine;
util>cmd += " }" + Environment.NewLine;
util>cmd += " Remove-PSSession -Session $pssessSql" + Environment.NewLine;
util>cmd += " exit";
util>try {
util>IList<System.Management.Automation.PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
util>runspace.Close();
util>return results;
util>}
```

If I capture the script going to the Invoke it works by replacing "\r\n" with a newline, why wouldn't it work in C#, I have a other scripts working from the C# so may be missing something obvious, here's the captured code that runs from a ps prompt:

```
$hasSnapin = get-pssnapin | Select { $_.Name.toLower().Trim() = 'sqlservercmdletsnapin100' }
if ($hasSnapin -eq $null) { Add-Pssnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100 }
$pssessSql = New-PSSession -ComputerName Server54
Invoke-Command -session $pssessSql -ScriptBlock {
sqlps -nologo -noprofile -command {
$srv = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server('Server54')
$srv.Logins | where-object {$_.Name -like 'DOMAIN\Server55$' } | select-object 'State' }
 }
 Remove-PSSession -Session $pssessSql
 exit
```

Thanks for any clues, I've had trouble with nested quotes but able to get most of those so this is I think from the \r\n's in the code but not sure how to find that out, I can't get the results to return from the app but the whole script does fine via a ps prompt.

Comment: `Get-PSSnapin` takes a `-name` parameter that takes case in-sensitive wildcard. So you can replace that `get-pssnapin | select...` with `Get-PSSnapin -name sqlserver*100`.

Answer (score 0):

Could the problem be the loading of the snapin on the remote end?

You have:

```
cmd = prep;
cmd = "$pssessSql ...";
```

which means that the prep code is completely ignored/overwritten by the second assignment.
One alternative is is to unconditionally add the snapin, specifying that you want errors to be ignored.

```
Add-Pssnapin -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, caught that between posts but may not have so appreciate you spotting it.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, the code is fine but I was using formatting, when I commented that out I was able to get my results. Before that it was returning formatting objects but I couldn't get values from them ... glad I tried without:

```
query += "\r\n" + "$data = $cmdCheckLogin.ExecuteReader()";
query += "\r\n" + "$dt = new-object System.Data.DataTable";
query += "\r\n" + "$dt.Load($data)";
query += "\r\n" + "$dt";    // | format-table -hidetableheaders";
query += "\r\n" + "$conn.Close()";
```